# Baseline Profile will benefit only for very First App Launch only?

Tags: baseline-profile, macrobenchmark

I have implemented Baseline Profile for Android. I can see baseline.prof in assets/dexopt
Also, profileinstaller dependency is already added. But still not clear about its benefits?

1. Baseline profile will just help with better TTID for very first user app launch only or even after multiple cold launches(without data clearing).
2. I uploaded my app on Internal Tracking. How can I check if profiles are being downloaded and installed after downloading app from PlayStore?

Is there any log around it? I tried checking with "ProfileInstaller" but there was no logs for my package(after implementing baseline profiles)

Answer (score 0):

1. Baseline Profiles don't only help for startup ([TTID](https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/vitals/launch-time#time-initial) + [TTFD](https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/vitals/launch-time#time-full)), but also for runtime performance reducing jank. The effect is not only for the first launch. Imagine this. without profiles, your app would need to precompile the code during runtime. The startup code might be precompiled during first launch, but certainly not the features that are post startup, for example a checkout flow in an e-commerce app. BPs will improve the runtime performance of that checkout flow during installation.
2. You can add [ProfileVerifier](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/profileinstaller/ProfileVerifier) (part of androidx.profileinstaller) to your app and report the status of a profile to a remote service.